# React google location doesnt work with Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was trying the react google api in my project. I created the count in Google Cloud and i have the api. 
I have this code:

```
import { GoogleComponent } from "react-google-location";
export default function Home() {

  const API_KEY_GOOGLE = "XXXXX";
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <h1>GHome</h1>

      <div>
        <GoogleComponent
          apiKey={API_KEY_GOOGLE}
          language={"en"}
          country={"country:in|country:us"}
          coordinates={true}
          //   locationBoxStyle={"custom-style"}
          //   locationListStyle={"custom-style-list"}
          onChange={e => {
            setPlace({ place: e });
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
      );
}
```

And appears that in the console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the application does not contain any other part where you have for example `<ul>` and `<li>` combinations or generating other HTML elements with `map()` without added `key` attribute for example then the issue is most probably with passed `country` attribute.

Based on the documentation of [`react-google-location`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-location#use-multiple-languages):

> Use multiple languages
>
> Pass key and value pair in the country object like this:
>
> `country={in|country:pr|country:vi|country:gu|country:mp}`

Your `country` attribute has `{"country:in|country:us"}`. Maybe it is worth to test as the following:

```
<GoogleComponent
    apiKey={API_KEY_GOOGLE}
    language={"en"}
    country={"in|country:us"}
    coordinates={true}
    onChange={e => {
       setPlace({ place: e });
    }} />
```

Or my second guess:

```
<GoogleComponent
    apiKey={API_KEY_GOOGLE}
    language={"en"}
    country={"in|country:in|country:us"}
    coordinates={true}
    onChange={e => {
       setPlace({ place: e });
    }} />
```

I hope that helps!